# How to make the results div beneath search input floated and not increasing the menu height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a search form:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>
            <form>
                <input type='text' name='search' class='search'/>
                <input type='submit' value='Go' />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class='results'></div>
```

The Jquery:

```
 var inputWidth = $('.search').width();
 $('.results').css('width' , inputWidth);
```

The `div` with class `results` will be containing a results from Database , I want this div to be out of the navigation menu beneath the search input having the same width.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using jQuery to set the width.. Can't you just use css and set both `search` and `results` to the same width?

If you *must* use jQuery for some reason, perhaps try this, it seems like you are missing the `px` at the end of your `.css()`:

```
 var inputWidth = $('.search').width();
 $('.results').css('width', inputWidth + 'px');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your work not having any problem .
**Check this for more detail out .**

```js
var inputWidth = $('.search').width();
$('.results').css('width' , inputWidth);
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

input {
 background: red;
  border: 0;
}
.results {
 background: red;
 margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" class="search"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="results">Some Search Result..</div>
```